# Should I "add" each new file in git if I did "add ." at the beginning?

Tags: git, addition

I have versioned my folder with

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m 'Initial commit'
```

Should I do

```
git add <newfile>
```

for each new file I create in .? Doesn't adding entire folder mean that all new files tracked automatically?

Thanks.

Comment: You can list the files tracked by git with `git ls-files`. This would allow you to answer the question by yourself. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to `git add` new files that you want to track.

`git add .` only adds what is currently in there at the time you call it. That means that when you make some changes and add some files, then you can again do `git add .` in the project root and it will add all those changes.

(Also check out the "interactive" add mode (`git add -i`). It's really practical.)

Comment: +1, but I would like to add that `git add .` will also add files like automatic backups (`prog.py~` files, etc.). It might therefore be a good idea to `git add` specific files, possibly automatically (like in `git add *.py`).

Comment: @EOL: it doesn't if you have your `.gitignore` set up to exclude them.

Comment: Certainly, but this is not a standard situation, as far as I know.

Comment: @EOL: having that sort of temporary file in your `.gitignore` is quite common. Some people actually set those in they global gitignore config.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you do.

Git does not track directories, it only tracks files (This has the interesting behaviour that you can't check in an empty directory). When you do `git add .` what you are saying is *"add all the files in the current directory and its sub-directories into the to-be-commited (staging) area"*.

You will also need to call `git add <filename>` (or do `git add -i`) for any file you have changed and want to commit. This is to move them into the "staging" area, where they will then be commited.